# Adding refs to components passed in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a component that takes a list of other components as a prop and then renders one of those components as a child according to an index held in the parent's state.

Ultimately I want to be able to call the 'getValidation' function of a child element in the array using imperative handler and forwardRef methodology. I've done this for a single child component but can't figure out how to do it with an array of children. I thought about creating an array of refs in the parent component but couldn't get that right. Would appreciate any help and alternative ways of going about this are more than welcome.

E.g.
Parent:

```
import React,  {createRef, useRef, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
const Parent = props => {
  const [currentChildIndex, setCurrentChildIndex] = useState(0);
  return (
     <div className='parent'>
         {
             props.children[currentChildIndex]
         }
     </div>
  )
};
export default Parent;
```

Child:

```
import React,  {forwardRef, useEffect, useImperativeHandle, useRef} from 'react';
const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {

  isValidated() {
    //stuff that validates the form
    return true;
  }    

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    getValidation() {
        return isValidated();
    }
  }));

  return (
     <div className='child'>
         {form with inputs and things}
     </div>
  )
});
export default Child;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it but I was having trouble asigning the refs to my array from inside the render method of the Parent component so I made a function to render the child component and called that from the render method and it seems to be working:

```
import React,  {createRef, useRef, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
const Parent = props => {
  const [currentChildIndex, setCurrentChildIndex] = useState(0);

  function renderChildComponent(CurrentComponent) {
      return (
          <CurrentComponent ref={childRefs[currentChildIndex] = createRef()} />
      )
   }

  return (
     <div className='parent'>
         {
             renderChildComponent(props.children[currentChildIndex])
         }
     </div>
  )
};
export default Parent;
```